# How to check if cabinets are wood or laminate

Tags: wood

When i move in to my new home i will more than likely need to do touching up in the kitchen.

How can i find if the cupboard doors are made from wood or laminated MDF?

Comment: A picture would really be helpful. Are they painted or stained?

Comment: I am more wanting to know how to identify this myself, but i will get a picture as an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way is to cut one in half, but I'll assume you want to do this non-destructively.

One way that you can check is to remove one of the hinges.  If it's a recessed hinge you'll find yourself looking at the inside of the door.  If it isn't recessed you can examine the screw holes and/or probe them with a dental pick.

Comment: Excellent idea, taking the hinge off would let me see the internal structure. I'm sure i can identify solid wood, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to tell, is to make an inconspicuous cut, such as underneath the frame of an upper cabinet, or under where the hinges sit.

If you want to tell before buying a house, or you don't want to make any marks. You can usually tell the difference by examining the edges of any piece. On most laminates (such as IKEA furniture) there will be a solid color along the edge where two faces meet, where the internal color of the laminate sheet is exposed. Solid wood will not show this characteristic line.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will keep it in mind for future.